# How can i retrieve the default value of a given structure in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

If I execute the following statement:

```
dim defaultDate as Date = Nothing
```

`defaultDate` contains the default value of the `Date` structure

I suspect there is a clean way to retreive this value, like some kind of buitin constant, but i was not able to find it.

**Q:** What is the clean way to retrieve the default value of a given structure in VB.net ?

Comment: It really surprises me you can get data like that without an exception being thrown.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I can assure you that this line does not crash. This is the way i currently retrieve the default value, and it works

Comment: Nah, I just meant it surprised me and was interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already found, `Nothing` is the correct way to do this in VB.NET for value types.

C# has a more "explicit" way of doing that with `default(T)`.

Comment: So there is no exact equivalent of default(T) in VB ?

Comment: @SamuelRossille `Nothing` actually is `default(T)` in VB.NET. http://stackoverflow.com/a/303525/492405 Most people assume that `Nothing` in VB.NET means "null". It actually means "The default value", and for all reference types that happens to be null. For value types, it's the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Value types does not need explicit initialization.

By default all the fields are initialized to default values.

```
dim defaultDate as Date ' Nothing not required
Console.WriteLine(defaultDate) ' 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Explanation on default constructor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333840/649524) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204009/649524)

Answer (score 1):

The default `Date` is [`Date.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx).

0:00:00 (midnight) on January 1, 0001.

[Date Data Type (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Dim d As Date = Nothing
If d = Date.MinValue Then
    ' yes, we are really here '
End If
```

I usually prefer `Date.MinValue` instead of `Nothing`, but i assume that's a matter of taste.

Comment: I'd say OP is looking for a way to get the default date for any given structure, not just date.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: OP wanted to know this constant: _"is there a clean way to retreive this value, like some kind of buitin constant, but i was not able to find it. "_ **Edit** Oh, you're right, i've missed the very last part.

Comment: @TimSchmelter should have been more explicit right from the start ;=)... but why do you call me OP ? What does it means ?

Comment: @SamuelRossille: It's just an abbreviation for _original poster_ http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OP (on SO he who asked the question)