# HashSet equality with custom objects and get one element

Tags: c#

I have the following class and a HashSet of it:

```
public class VersionSettings {
  public String Culture { get; set; }
  public String Domain { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }    
}

HashSet<VersionSetting> vs = ...
```

**Questions**

1. I would like two VersionSettings to be equal when Culture is the same.

   In this moment it is not what happens. How can i solve this?
2. Would be possible to get a VersionSetting from the HashSet using:

   var b = vs["en-US"];

   Maybe using some HashSet extension?

Comment: Maybe you need a Dictionary<string, VersionSettings> instead of a HashSet

Comment: Yes, that would be an option but I would like to keep the Culture inside the VersionSetting object.

Comment: You can have it as both as the dictionary key and one of your classe's properties in which case you build your dictionary with versionSettings.ToDictionary(setting => setting.Culture)

Comment: Re your second question... you really want a dictionary. HashSets fundamentally don't let you retrieve their contents other than by iterating over them.

Comment: @MDMoura: note that i've edited my answer since i've overlooked the second equestion until now.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to not only compare references what [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) does:

```
public class VersionSettings
{
    public String Culture { get; set; }
    public String Domain { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        VersionSettings other = obj as VersionSettings;
        if(other == null) return false;
        return Culture == other.Culture;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Culture == null ? 0 : Culture.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Another approach is to implement a custom  `IEqualityComparer<VersionSettings>` which does not require to modify the class itself:

```
public class VersionSettingComparer : IEqualityComparer<VersionSettings>
{
    public bool Equals(VersionSettings x, VersionSettings y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Culture == y.Culture;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(VersionSettings obj)
    {
        if(obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.Culture == null ? 0 : obj.Culture.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the constructor of `HashSet<T>`:

```
var vs = new HashSet<VersionSettings>(new VersionSettingComparer());
```

---

According to your second question how you can access the `HashSet<VersionSetting>` in this way:

```
var enUsSetting = vs["en-US"];
```

That doesn't work because a hashset has no indexer like a collection or dictionary. You probably want a  `Dictionary<string, VersionSettings>` instead.

As simple but not that efficient workaround you can use LINQ:

```
var enUsSetting = vs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Culture == "en-US");
```

If you want to create the mentioned dictionary you can also use LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, VersionSettings> cultureLoookup = vs
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Culture, x => x);  // you only need to create this once
```

Now this works:

```
var enUsSetting = cultureLoookup["en-US"];
```

Comment: Your `Equals` is broken syntactically. Also am not sure Why are you checking for `null` explicitly in `Equals`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: why is it broken? I'm checking for `null` because it's possible that it's null. Either because the passed object is not a `VersionSettings` or because it's reference is `null`. In both cases they are not equal.

Comment: Your equality comparer says that two null objects aren't equal.

Comment: @Servy: why should two null objects supposed to be equal? I have no informations about them so i refuse to treat them as if they were equal. But OP is free to change that implementation detail. **Edit** However, i'll change it since i've noticed that even `Object.Equals` does return true then.

Comment: Well if no `null` objects are ever equal then you'll never be able to remove it from the set, ever.  `Contains` on `null` will return `false`, even if there are (multiple) `null` items in the set, all of the superset/subset methods have the same problem.  Basically all you can ever do is add the item to the set, and after that it'd only ever cause a big mess.

Comment: @Servy: that's a good point and explains why it seems to be a guideline in .NET to treat two null objects as equal. In sql `NULL` is never equal to something else (what was the reason for my implementation). But even VB.NET returns `False` for `Nothing <> NotNothing`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15524045/284240

Answer (score 0):

Why in a simple way you doesn't use `Dictionary<string, VersionSettings>`. For instace:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, VersionSettings>();
settings["en-US"] = usSettings;   
settings["es-ES"] = esSettings;
...
var currentSetting = settings[currentSettingIdText];
```

It is just a tip.