# VB.NET LINQ Method Syntax disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I run into trouble when learning more about the Entity Framework and LINQ.

I am trying to find values from a database that match a specific date.

I have 1.250.000 entries and 36300 of them are from a specific date.

I am using plain old SQL until now and want to practice LINQ to refactor my application to work with the EF.

Can you tell where my mistake is?

The second way works but takes a lot of time ~15 sec

[image]

Comment: Next error: append `ToList` to create a list. According to the other, try: `Where(Function(d) d.ExportedDate.HasValue AndAlso d.ExportedDate.Value = exportDate)`

Comment: You could put this as answer and explain me why your code works without problems if you have time to. I would mark this as answer.Thanks! :)

Comment: This warning is not specific to LINQ whatsoever.

Comment: @user6144226 specific to what then so that I can do some research?

Comment: Hint hint: Option Strict

Comment: @user6144226 By adding the .HasValue property my issue got solved. No matter how long I search in the official article of MS I would have never found the solution there by search for Option Strict. So it doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Where(Function(d) d.ExportedDate.HasValue AndAlso d.ExportedDate.Value = exportDate)
```

On this way you select only rows where  the nullable column `ExportedDate` is not null and where it equals the given date. `ExportedDate.Value` returns `Date` as opposed to `d.ExportedDate` which is a `Date?`. If you compare a `Date?` with a `Date` you get a `Boolean?` as result(not a `Boolean`), because `Nothing` means undefined.

This is an interesting difference to C#, related: [Why is there a difference in checking null against a value in VB.NET and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524045/why-is-there-a-difference-in-checking-null-against-a-value-in-vb-net-and-c)

To fix the next error: append `ToList` to create a list.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the Date? and Boolean?. Never heard of it until now. That will help me in future. Makes totally sense now. +1